# Randomly choose an item from a javascript array without repeating or destroying the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to serve words from an array to the user each time a button is clicked. I would like to serve the words randomly and not repeat. However, I don't want to splice the served word from the array (ultimately the array items are going to be audio recordings for dictation and I want the user to be able to repeat the word if necessary).

I have tried a few things and most shortest solutions seem to involve splicing the array which ultimately destroys it. This, I don't think, is correct for my case.

Here is the code (and [here it is in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bL8wz3q/3/)):

```
var usedModuleOneWords = [];
var moduleOneArray = ["sit", "sat", "mat"];
var combined = (moduleOneArray, usedModuleOneWords);

const placeWordFromList = function() {
    for (const v of new Set([...moduleOneArray, ...usedModuleOneWords]))
        if (moduleOneArray.filter(e => e === v).length !== usedModuleOneWords.filter(e => e === v).length)
            {
            const randomWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * moduleOneArray.length);
            const displayWord = (randomWord, moduleOneArray[randomWord]);
            document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = displayWord;
            usedModuleOneWords.push(displayWord);
            console.log(usedModuleOneWords);
            } else {
            console.log("All Words Used!");
        }
}
```

Comment: You are creating soo many intermediate arrays. Copy the original word-list *(remove duplicates, if necessary)* shuffle it and return the entries from that shuffled list one after another.

Comment: What do you think these are doing `var combined = (moduleOneArray, usedModuleOneWords);` and `const displayWord = (randomWord, moduleOneArray[randomWord]);`? It is valid JS, but it makes no sense the way you use it, so I'd guess you confuse this construct with something else.

Comment: Yes, that's why I ended up here. I am new to coding and JS and was trying to follow various tutorials and guides but just found the code was getting knottier and knottier. I appreciate the feedback though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think it simple

```
const placeWordFromList = function() {
    let randWord = moduleOneArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * moduleOneArray.length)];
    console.log(randWord);
    
    if(usedModuleOneWords.length >= moduleOneArray.length){
        console.log('All words are used!');
    } else if(usedModuleOneWords.indexOf(randWord) == -1){
      console.log(randWord);
      document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = randWord;
      usedModuleOneWords.push(randWord);
    } else{
      placeWordFromList();
    }
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g5re6tf/1/)

Comment: Thank you this is really clean and I more or less understand the entire thing - could you explain the indexOf method part of the code?

Comment: `indexOf` searches and returns the index of found item of array. For more informations: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf